# Does this map define a rational map?

Tags: affine-geometry

$\phi(x,y)=\frac{y-x^2}{x^2}$ for $\phi:X\to\mathbb{A}^1(\mathbb{C})$

$X$ being a variety $X=V(\langle x^5-x^4+2x^2y-y^2\rangle) \subset \mathbb{A}^2(\mathbb{C})$

Comment: Does $X=A$? Because you didn't define $X$.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I fixed it

Comment: You can use "\to" to get $\to$. :)

Answer (score 0):

A rational map is an equivalence class of maps defined on open subsets of $X$. The map you defined above is defined on the open subset of $X \subseteq \mathbb A^2(\mathbb C)$ where $x \neq 0$, so it represents a rational map.

Hope that helps,

Comment: can you explain how I show explicitly that the map is defined on the set X?

Comment: @B Dill : It's not "defined as a map" on $X$, as a map, it's only defined on an open subset. But this means it defines a rational map on $X$ by definition.

Comment: Does it suffice for me to say, "x5−x4+2x2y−y2  are elements of the function field of X therefore φ is a rational map on X?

Comment: @B Dill : The map $x^5 - x^4 + 2x^2 - y^2$ is identically zero on $X$. Actually, all you need to show is that the set of points in $\mathbb A^2(\mathbb C)$ where $\phi$ is defined intersects $X$ in a non-empty set, so that the rational map is well-defined. I suggest you read up on your definitions, you sound confused!